# Can I get event details from a personal fb account(not page) to to my website?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am able to fetch event details in my `php` based website through Facebook graph API only if the event is uploaded in `facebook` page. But if I use a personal `fb` account instead of `fb` page I am not able to get any data. In both cases I am using same access token, App ID and Secret key, the only variable is `facebook` account id. I could not find any answers on internet so kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`user_events`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_events) permission from the user whose events you want to read.

Comment: I want to access my own event. It is a public event and I don't want "Log in with facebook" button. I want to use those events to show on my website

Comment: And my event privacy is set to public plus I have also set my account priivacy settings to public.

Comment: That doesn’t matter. Public on facebook.com does not necessarily mean publicly available via API as well. It is a user event, and as such needs permission from the user to read it. If you don’t like that – then create a page, and publish your events via that.